# Selenium Webdriver for retrieving tables from a webpage

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Can selenium webdriver be used to retrieve data presented in tables?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, that you want to retrieve some text from a webpage, then yes, absolutely.

Comment: I definitely know you can retrieve text from a webpage, but in this case, I'm trying to retrieve various texts organized in a table. So I am wondering whether or not I can just retrieve the table.

Comment: And how do you expect it to be returned, in what format? You can either have the whole tabel contents concatenated (usually not a good thing) or you have to itarate over it and pull out everything you need manually.

Comment: Since this process has to be done several times, doing everything manually seems to be out of the question. So I would have to say concatenated.

Comment: Well, then just do `getText()` on the table and see what is returned.

Comment: I think you need to look up [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) documentation. If you use the correct locators you can retrieve any displayed text from a webpage with Selenium, table included (td elements).

Answer (score 0):

Yes Selenium WebDriver can be used to retrieve data from tables.Follow the below C# code to retrieve data from a table. To demonstrate this I have used a table with id="accounts" in "http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datasource/datasource_table_to_array.html".

```
<table id="accounts"> 
    <caption>Table in markup with data in it</caption>
    <thead> 
           <tr> 
                <th>Due Date</th> 
                <th>Account Number</th> 
                <th>Quantity</th> 
                <th>Amount Due</th> 
           </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
           <tr> 
                <td>1/23/1999</td> 
                <td>29e8548592d8c82</td> 
                <td>12</td> 
                <td>$150.00</td> 
           </tr> 
           <tr> 
                <td>5/19/1999</td> 
                <td>83849</td> 
                <td>8</td> 
                <td>$60.00</td> 
           </tr> 
            ... 
   </tbody> 
</table>
```

Details of the code.

1. Created a Web Element for  of the  By.XPath("//table[@id='accounts']/thead/tr")
2. Created an IList with collection of all the  tag web elements under the **/thead/tr** By.XPath("//table[@id='accounts']/thead/tr/th")
3. Access the contents of the table head using a loop.
4. Created a Web Element for  of the  By.XPath("//table[@id='accounts']/tbody/tr")
5. Created a IList with collection of all the  tag web elements under the /tbody/tr By.XPath("//table[@id='accounts']/tbody/tr/th")
6. Access the contents of the table body using a loop.

-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace BusinessCreation
{
    class ExtractDataFromATable
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datasource/datasource_table_to_array.html");
          if(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='accounts']/thead/tr/th")).Displayed)
            {
                IWebElement webElementHead =  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='accounts']/thead/tr"));
                IList<IWebElement> ElementCollectionHead = webElementHead.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@id='accounts']/thead/tr/th"));
                foreach (IWebElement item in ElementCollectionHead)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Text);
                }
            }
            if (driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='accounts']/tbody/tr")).Displayed)
            {
                IWebElement webElementBody = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='accounts']/tbody/tr"));
                IList<IWebElement> ElementCollectionBody = webElementBody.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@id='accounts']/tbody/tr"));
                foreach (IWebElement item in ElementCollectionBody)
                {
                    string []arr= new string[4];
                    arr = item.Text.Split(' ');
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
                    }               
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```